# Custom image viewing slows down

Tags: android, android-layout, optimization, time

## The problem

Hi there,

I'm developing an application where the user specifies some pictures and how long they are going to be on the screen.So sometimes he wants to create something like a small animation or viewing the images for a small amount of time.The problem is that after some time the images are not previewed when they should and we have a few ms of error.In the application that i'm developing time matters so I would like some help on what the problem might be.

## The code

So let me explain how it works.I take the pictures from my web app and then I save them in a HashMap

```
Bitmap image = ImageOperations(url,String.valueOf(frameNum) + ".jpg");

ImageMap.put(String.valueOf(frameNum), image);
```

where the mathod ImageOperations is like that:

```
private Bitmap ImageOperations(String url, String saveFilename) {
        try {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
            Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            if (theImage.getHeight() >= 700 || theImage.getWidth() >= 700) {
                theImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(theImage,
                        display.getWidth(), display.getHeight() - 140, true);
            }
            return theImage;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

So later I run a thread that updates the UI when the user specified.The method that updates it is this one.

```
public void setPictures(int NumOfFrame) {
if (frameArray.get(NumOfFrame - 1).frame_pic.contains("n/a") != true) {
ImagePlace.setImageBitmap(ImageMap.get(String.valueOf(NumOfFrame)));
} else {
        ImagePlace.setImageDrawable(null);
}

}
```

After we update the image we put the thread for sleep and when runs again it updates the thread.Is there something that creates the problem?Does it have to do with Garbage collection?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How many images do You have in ImageMap?

Comment: The number of the picture varies from 5-30. For the animation the most pictures are repeating. Like the user says i want picture 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4 to be viewed with that sequence and the app puts them in the UI

Answer (score 1):

Probably the issue is in increasing heap size when it loads additional images. I would suggest You to do some [profiling](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) so things will be much clearer and You'll get full picture of timings for the app.

Comment: I get all the timing logs as a text file in my server and then I do all the analysis using matlab.If the issue is with the heap size what can i do?

Comment: Try to reduce its usage, e.g. You could try to 'preallocate' some heap size before start image loading or store less image (mean, save resized copies in cache folder and have only fixed number of images in the map at the moment, LruCache could be useful for it)

Comment: So that means that i should keep my hashmap but put the images that appear most to the LruCache.So when i want to load an image i check if the bitmap with the specific exists in the LruCache is kept there and load it otherwise load from the Hashmap and add in the cache?

Comment: No, storing images in HashMap won't be needed in that case, because loaded images will be stored only in LruCache. Checkout http://code.google.com/p/libs-for-android/source/browse/#git%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fandroid%2Fimageloader as a good example of image loading.

Answer (score 0):

First you are missing a null check at here:

```
ImageMap.get(String.valueOf(NumOfFrame))
```

And you do not recycle the old bitmap at here:

```
theImage.recycle(); // missing line
theImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(theImage,
                        display.getWidth(), display.getHeight() - 140, true);
```

It may lead to outofmemory exceptions, with is most likely from your description of the problem.

Also I am not sure if `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` throw exception when he fails. You need to add a null point check there too.

Comment: I'm doing null check with other ways inside the app.I don't have any issues that lead to outOFmemory exception.I get all of my bitmaps from the hashmap

Comment: @vlad_o When you perform scaling you create new bitmap without destroying the old one.

Comment: @Balibu Thanx.I added the recycle but I still have the problem.Maybe i have to reduce the usage of the heap : /

Comment: @vlad_o It's easy to test: Create a demo app, that add new photo on each click, if the app will crush on every X click, then you know that this is your problem.